# Finding complex roots $z^3 = 4\sqrt{2}(-1 + i)$

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm trying to find the complex roots of $z^3 = 4\sqrt{2}(-1 + i)$.

Here is what I've done:

I've figured that this should be equivalent to

$$z = 2(cos(-\frac{\pi}{12} + \frac{2k\pi}{3}) + isin(-\frac{\pi}{12} + \frac{2k\pi}{3}))$$

$$root_1 = 2e^{-\frac{\pi}{12}i}$$
$$root_2 = 2e^{\frac{7\pi}{12}i}$$
$$root_2 = 2e^{\frac{15\pi}{12}i}$$

Yet I'm not sure if my answer is correct, since the actual answer looks very different:

$root_1 = \sqrt{2}(1+i)$

$root_2 = -\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i + \frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}i$

$root_3 = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}i - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i$

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that your answer has the wrong norm...

Comment: @IgorRivin why though? $|z| = 8$ and  $8^{\frac{1}{3}} = 2$, and the angle is just $-\frac{\pi}{4} * \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Yes, you are right, mental calculation error on my part :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is slight mistake. Note that $\arg (-1+i) = 3\pi /4$, not $-\pi/4$.

Hence for $k=0,1,2$
$$z=2 \exp \left\{ i\left( \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{2k\pi}{3}\right) \right\} $$

Now you can evaluate.

Comment: Isn't $3\pi/4$ outside of the range of the arctan? Since the angle is just $arctan(-1)$

Comment: @JakeDrone $(-1+i)$ lies in second quadrant. So its argument $\in (\pi/2, \pi)$ which you can obtain correctly by $\pi + \tan^{-1}(-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

The argument of your $z$ equals $3\pi/4.$ So, the roots should be $2\exp(i\pi/4), 2 \exp(i(\pi/4 + 2\pi/3)), 2\exp(i(\pi/4 + 4\pi/3)).$ The arguments are

$\pi/4, 11\pi/12, 17\pi/12$

Comment: Isn't $3\pi/4$ outside of the range of the arctan? Since the angle is just $arctan(-1)$